# Conversion fails in Visual Studio 11 beta

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am adding an existing project written in VS 2010 (MVC 3) to a VS 11 solution. It tries to add the project to the solution and gives this error:

`Operation cannot be completed. The project file xxx cannot be converted. See the conversion report for more details.`

Where can I find the conversion report? What is generally the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **remember** that Visual Studio 2011 is in a beta format, and it's normal to errors occur, *for example* I can't run a project of mine made in MVC 4, but fires up fine in Visual Studio 2010...

As for your question, from MSDN Library you can read about the conversion as:

> A report named **ConversionReport.txt is created and stored in the root directory of the converted Web project**. This report file lists all the changes that were made to your Web project, and it might contain informational comments, warnings, and errors that were found during conversion. If you select the option in the conversion wizard to show the conversion log after the wizard is complete, you will see a conversion report in Visual Studio 2005. For more information about the format of this report, see Migration Conversion Report Format.

there are more resources for this

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4c218a0-8f31-49a2-ba78-c9c4188be5b3(v=vs.90)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4c218a0-8f31-49a2-ba78-c9c4188be5b3%28v=vs.90%29)

They are for older version of Visual Studio, but the process remains the same...